# Use await with react-native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am retrieving a password asynchronously and this is working fine:

```
static async login(){
let password = await User.getPassword();
alert(password); // this works, password is shown
```

But if I want to use it inside fetch it dose not work

```
static async login(){
let password = await User.getPassword();
alert(password); // this works, password is shown
      return fetch(userInfoURL,
        { method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Authorization':  password,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
```

the password received by the server is empty

I also tried

```
User.getPassword().then((password) => {
return fetch(userInfoURL,
            { method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Authorization':  password,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          })
```

but I had the same problem, password is empty.

Comment: If the `alert` is showing the password, then it's definitely working in that object initializer. If it's not getting passed on, it's nothing to do with `async`/`await`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: For instance, running [this MCVE](https://pastebin.com/jBGGzAKn) locally, I definitely see the `Authorization: foo` header sent with the GET.

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the fetch

```
return await fetch(userInfoURL,
   { method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization':  password,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async getTabList(userId){
    try{
        let params = 'userId='+userId;

        let myR = await myRequest([yourURL],params);
        let response = await fetch(myR);
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        if(responseJson.code === 0){
            return responseJson;
        }else{
            Toast.fail('失败');
            return {};
        }
    } catch (error){
        Toast.fail('异常，请联系管理员');
    }
}

function myRequest(url,params){
    return new Request(url,{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // 加密
        },
        body:params,
    });
}
```